# Excel - VLOOKUP vs. INDEX/MATCH - Which is better?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I understand how to use each method: `VLOOKUP` (or `HLOOKUP`) vs. `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

I'm looking for differences between them not in terms of personal preference, but primarily in the following areas:

1. Is there something that one method can do that the other cannot?
2. Which one is more efficient in general (or does it depend on the situation)?
3. Any other advantages/disadvantages to using one method vs. the other

**NOTE**: I am answering my own question here but looking to see if anyone else has other insights I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Just a note - this question is quite broad for SO, and is a lot of opinion (but yes, there are quantifiable reasons to use one over the other I'm sure).  You can find many pages just by searching online that compare these two in great detail.

Comment: @BruceWayne Good point. I had seen many of these comparisons before excluding the fixed column index number which isn't discussed much, so I figured I would share.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I prefer to use `INDEX`/`MATCH` in practically every situation because it is far more flexible and has the potential to be much more efficient depending on how large the lookup table is.

The only time when I can really justify using `VLOOKUP` is for very straight-forward tables where the column index number is dynamic, although even in this case, `INDEX`/`MATCH` is equally viable.

I'll give a few specific examples below to demonstrate the detailed differences between the two methods.

---

**INDEX/MATCH can lookup to the left** *(or anywhere else you want)*

This is probably the most obvious advantages to `INDEX`/`MATCH` as well as one of the biggest downfalls of `VLOOKUP`. `VLOOKUP` can only lookup to the right, `INDEX`/`MATCH` can lookup from any range, including different sheets if necessary.

The example below cannot be accomplished with `VLOOKUP`.

[image]

---

**INDEX/MATCH has the potential to use smaller cell ranges** (thus increasing efficiency)

Consider the example below. It can be accomplished with either method.

[image]

[image]

Both of these formulas work fine. However, since the `VLOOKUP` formula contains a larger range than the `INDEX`/`MATCH` formula, it is unnecessarily volatile.

If any cell in the range `B1:G4` changes, the `VLOOKUP` formula must recalculate (because `B1:G4` is within the range `A1:H4`) even though changing any cell in `B1:G4` will not affect the outcome of the formula. This is not an issue for `INDEX`/`MATCH` because its formula does not contain the range `B1:G4`.

---

**Using VLOOKUP with fixed col_index_number is dangerous**

The main issue I see with having a fixed column index number is that it will not update as it should if full columns are inserted. Consider the following example:

[image]

This formula works fine unless a column is inserted within the lookup table. In that case, the formula will lookup the value to the left of where it should. See below, result after a column has been inserted.

[image]

This can actually be alleviated by using the following `VLOOKUP` formula instead:

```
= VLOOKUP("s",A1:H4,COLUMN(H1)-COLUMN(A1)+1,FALSE)
```

Now `H1` will automatically update to `I1` if a column is inserted, thus preserving the reference to the same column. However, this is entirely unnecessary because `INDEX`/`MATCH` can accomplish this without this problem with the formula below.

```
= INDEX(H1:H4,MATCH("s",A1:A4,0))
```

I realize this is an unlikely scenario, but it always bothered me that `VLOOKUP` by default looks up based on a fixed column index that does not automatically update if columns are inserted. To me, it just seems to make the `VLOOKUP` function more fragile.

---

**INDEX/MATCH can handle variable column indexes just as well, but longer formula**

If the column index number itself is dynamic, this is really the only case when I think `VLOOKUP` simplifies things a bit, but again the `INDEX`/`MATCH` alternative is just as good, just slightly more confusing. See below examples.

[image]

[image]

---

**INDEX/MATCH is more efficient for multiple lookups**

*(thanks to @jeffreyweir)*

If multiple lookup values are needed for a single match value, it is much more efficient to have a helper cell with the match value. This way, the match only has to be computed once, instead of one for each lookup formula. See example below.

[image]

This match value can then be used to return the appropriate lookup values. See example below, (formula has been dragged to the right).

[image]

This manual "splitting" of the match value and index values is not an option with `VLOOKUP` since the match value is an "internal" variable in `VLOOKUP` and cannot be accessed.

---

**INDEX/MATCH can look up a range, allowing another operation**

Let's say for example you want to find a max value in a column based on the column name.

You can first use `MATCH` to find the appropriate column, then `INDEX` to return the *range* of that entire column, then use `MAX` to find the max of that range.

See example below, the formula in `H4` looks up the max value of the column name specified in cell `G4`. This cannot be accomplished using `VLOOKUP` alone.

[image]

---

**MATCH doesn't have to match an exact value**

Usually `MATCH` is used with the third argument as `0`, meaning "find an exact match". But depending on the situation, using `-1` or `1` as the third argument of `MATCH` can be very useful.

For example, the following formula returns the row number of the last row in column `A` that contains a number:

```
= MATCH(-1E+300,A:A,-1)
```

This is because this formula starts from the bottom of the `A` column and works its way toward the top, and returns the first row number in the `A` column where the value is greater than or equal to -1E+300 (which is basically any number).

Then `INDEX` can be used in combination with this to return the value in that cell. See example below.

[image]

---

**In Summary**

`VLOOKUP` is, at best, as good as `INDEX`/`MATCH` and admittedly slightly less confusing in some situations. And at worst, `VLOOKUP` is much more unsafe and volatile than `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

Also worth noting that if you want to look up a *range* instead of a single value, `INDEX`/`MATCH` must be used. `VLOOKUP` cannot be used to look up a range.

For these reasons, I generally prefer `INDEX`/`MATCH` in practically all situations.

Comment: Once I learned `Index/Match`, I never went back.  You can manipulate your data (especially move columns around) and `Index/Match` will still work.  Unlike `VLOOKUP()`, the best thing for me is my data doesn't have to be in "left to right"  order. You can also do [multiple criteria Index/Match](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) much simpler than the `VLOOKUP()` equivalent, IMO.

Comment: In addition, the fact that a VLOOKUP functions points at an entire table of data – even though it only ever actually makes use of two columns of it (the key column on the far left, and the nth column given by the col_index_num argument) – means that any time you change any cell in that table, your VLOOKUP is going to recalculate. And then so are ALL formulas downstream of those VLOOKUPS. It’s exactly as if VLOOKUP is a volatile function. 
Whereas with INDEX/MATCH, your functions will ONLY recalculate if you change something in the specific columns that the INDEX and MATCH combo references.

Comment: Ah yes...it was. Most comprehensive answer I've seen on the topic, by the way.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Thank you. I often see `VLOOKUP` used in answers on SO at least one of these issues addressed in this answer, so I created this post so that I can refer those users to this answer.

Comment: For completeness, here's another reason to use INDEX/MATCH: the MATCH part can be split out to it's own cell, and reused (aka 'cached') in the event that you are using multiple VLOOKUPS to bring through additional columns related to a particular record. e.g. if you're looking up a Customer ID, and returning a Surname, a FirstName, and a Gender, say. Splitting out the MATCH component and using it to drive three INDEX functions is going to be upwards of three times more efficient than using three columns populated by VLOOKUP.

Comment: @jeffreyweir This is a great point. See my post, I edited to include this. Thanks!

Comment: One further reason: you can name the columns. `=INDEX(ClientName, XMATCH(@A:A,ClientId))`, very nice when looking up data from another sheet. Also - while demonstrating `INDEX / MATCH` to colleagues relatively recently - stumbled into `XMATCH` which is even nicer as you don't need the unclear `,0`