# Update a column in sheet 2 if another column in same sheet matches a column in sheet 1

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have 2 sheets in my excel workbook.

Sheet 1 has 3 columns

AccountNumber

City

Postcode

Sheet 2 has one coumn only namely AccountNumber.

I would like to update sheet 2 with city and postcode from sheet1, where the AccountNumber in both sheets match.

Is there a simple way of doing it without VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP is what you are looking for:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

The basic functionality is that you have a search parameter, a matrix to search in and a result row

=VLOOKUP(SEARCHPARAMETER;SEARCH_MATRIX;ROW_TO_RETURN;EXACT_MATCH_BOOLEAN)

There are plenty of examples around the web

Comment: I prefer `INDEX`/`MATCH` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348889/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-which-is-better)) but otherwise agree with your answer. +1