# Excel Formula - Return values from One Column based on Comparison between 2 Columns

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Hi all,

Is there an excel formula to print the values in Column A for values in Column C please?
 In order to obtain the Column A values use Column B.

For example

Name 5 in Column C, should print mjijij in Column D, based on Name 5 value Column B.

Regards,

Comment: Simple INDEX/MATCH will do it.

Comment: check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348889/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-which-is-better?rq=1  while not a duplicate question, the answer will give you all you need to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula on Column D1,

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$11,MATCH(C1,$B$1:$B$11,0),1)
```

Change the range as per your record.

Hope this helps you.