# How to populate a particular cell value between two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am facing problem to populate a cell value. 
For example i have two columns A and B as shown below

```html
A         B

381      369
382      370.3
384      370.3
385      371
386      372
```

My aim is to get the respective value of column B value 370.3 as 382.
I tried using Vlookup formula "=VLOOKUP(D3,A:B,2,TRUE)"

Please help me to find the correct code to get the solution as in the image 
[image: Open the image]

Comment: For a more thorough explanation of the difference between `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX`/`MATCH`, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348889/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-which-is-better) (and answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to find "370.3" ie the contents of cell D3 then you will need to match in column B and index in column A so:

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MATCH(D3,B1:B6,0))
```

VLOOKUP will not work as it indexes the leftmost column... or you change the data order.

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for. Thank you for the answer.