# How to use Index and Match to find a value when the column header is a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to pull a value from a data pile based on text value and quantity range. Using Index I can use Match to find the correct row but i cannot seem to find a way to get the correct column.

`=INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH(G2,A:A,0),[match(H2,1:1,1)])` == .7 in Value column below

[image: Table]

I am just getting errors for finding anything that belongs in the Value column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - VLOOKUP vs. INDEX/MATCH - Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348889/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-which-is-better)

Comment: `1-10`, `11-20` and `21-30` are text. Match based on text will most likely fail or not return what you want. You could return the results you want by changing the headers to 0, 10, and 20.

Comment: @BigBen, I believe your comment is helpful enough to be an answer.

Comment: @BigBen Agreed, then you can just use `IFERROR(MATCH(H2,$A$1:$D$1,1),0)+1` as the second argument...