# Create list of data if criteria is met

Tags: excel

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A              B               C               D
1      CW02       2020-01-06          CW03        2020-01-13
2      CW02       2020-01-07                      2020-01-14
3      CW02       2020-01-08                      2020-01-15
4      CW02       2020-01-09                      2020-01-16
5      CW02       2020-01-10                      2020-01-17
6      CW02       2020-01-11                      2020-01-18
7      CW02       2020-01-12                      2020-01-19
8      CW03       2020-01-13
9      CW03       2020-01-14
10     CW03       2020-01-15
11     CW03       2020-01-16
12     CW03       2020-01-17
13     CW03       2020-01-18
14     CW03       2020-01-19
15
16
```

In `Cell C1` I want to enter a calender week from `Column A`. In the example above `CW03`. 
Based on this criteria all days which refer to this calender week in `Column B` should be listed in `Column D`.

With `=VLOOKUP($C$1,$A:$B,2,FALSE)` I am only able to extract the first value.

What formula do I need to get the list?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Is `CW03` a result of any formula? What format is it?

Comment: Excel 2016 or younger

Comment: You cannot use VLOOKUP to look to the left of your matched column

Comment: [Excel - VLOOKUP vs. INDEX/MATCH - Which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348890/1422451)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER:

```
=FILTER(B:B,A:A=C1)
```

[image]

IF not put:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$14)/($A$1:$A$14=$C$1),ROW(ZZ1))),"")
```

And copy down.

[image]

If you data is always sorted on column A then you can use:

```
=IF(ROW(ZZ1)>COUNTIF(A:A,$C$1),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH($C$1,A:A,0)+ROW(ZZ1)-1))
```

And copy down.

[image]